# Django Custom API Endpoint with two parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to build a fairly simple API endpoint in a Django app I inherited.

I'm new to python and Django

The app uses views.py with classes that extend ModelViewSet.

It also uses a urls.py with entries like this:

```py
router.register('agent_licenses', views.AgentLicenseViewSet)
```

and this one I came up with:

```py
router.register(r'agent_licenses/(?P<agent_id>\d+)/<state_id>\d+/', views.AgentLicenseViewSet)
```

I need to build the fastest-responding endpoint possible and so I plan to use a custom SQL query that returns a True/False.

Is there some straightforward way to build an endpoint (hopefully in views.py, although if that's not possible, that's ok.) that will show up in Swagger without having to wrestle with Models, ModelViewSet, urls.py, Serializers, etc?

I have managed to get close, using the AgentLicenseViewSet, like this:  (Ignore the actual code in the endpoint method - it's just test code at this point)

```py
class AgentLicenseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Agent license REST view
    """

    queryset = models.AgentLicense.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.AgentLicenseSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = filters.AgentLicenseFilter

    @action(methods=["GET"], detail=True)
    # def has_license_in_state(self, agent_id: int, state_id: int) -> Response:
    def has_license_in_state(self, *_args, **_kwargs ) -> Response:
        #print(state_id)
        #print(pk)
        # return Response(data={'message': False})
        return Response(data=False)
        # return False
```

But - when I run this, I get an endpoint that appears to be ignoring the \d+ in the router.register line I made above ( it asks for strings instead of ints) and it insists that the primary key on the agent_license table MUST be included.

I just want to build an endpoint that shows up in Swagger, and takes two ints (but not the primary key on the table) so that I can use them to populate my custom query and get a true/false response, but if that's not possible, any advice on how to make DjangoSwagger see the two parameters (agent_id and state_id) as ints, and eliminate the requirement that the endpoint submit a primary key would also be welcomed.

Many thanks.

Here is a picture of the endpoint that I currently get in Swagger.

[image: Swagger Endpoint showing strings (instead of ints on the two fields) and primary key required]

Update: I find that although a breakpoint in my API method does not get hit when I exercise the endpoint via Swagger, the endpoint disappears when I remove it.  I can't explain that.

Answer (score 2):

first you have to make `detail=False` in your action decorator.
then you can access to state_id and agent_id like this:

```
@action(methods=["GET"], detail=False)
def has_license_in_state(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        state_id = kwargs.get("state_id")
        agent_id = kwargs.get("agent_id")
        # some codes
        return Response()
```

And for your swagger if you are using [drf-yasg](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) you can do something like this:

```
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema


state_id= openapi.Parameter(
    "state_id", openapi.IN_PATH, description="state_id", type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER
)
agent_id = openapi.Parameter(
    "agent_id", openapi.IN_PATH, description="agent_id ", type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER
)
```

and then use it as a decorator in your action:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[state_id, agent_id])
@action(methods=["GET"], detail=False)
def has_license_in_state(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        state_id = kwargs.get("state_id")
        agent_id = kwargs.get("agent_id")
        # some codes
        return Response()
```

Comment: Thank you @tohidsadeghian -- that worked.  It did add two fields to Swagger (I didn't try drf_yasg yet).  One field for "limit" and another for "offset".  Is there a way to eliminate those?

Comment: Also, I see that on a "path" statement, you can set the parameter's type to, say, int.  I've tried to use a path statement here, but it doesn't work any way I try it.  Are path statements somehow incompatible with either the router.register statements and/or showing up in Swagger?

Comment: I tried to use the path statement because it lets you set the type of the parameter.  I understand that you recommended another library for this.  Just wondering if there's a Django way to do it.  It seems that even if I define the parameter in the router.register line with regex that requires it to be numbers only, it still gets represented as a string on Swagger.  It's not a big deal - just trying to learn more about how Django does things and why my path statement doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: Hi @jb62.limit and offset comes from your rest-framework default_pagination_class in your `settings.py` so you can eliminate those in your configuration or set your pagination_class per view.

Answer (score 0):

tohid sadeghian's answer works.  I found an alternate path that does not add pagination fields to the Swagger page.  Here's how it works.

First I added this line to the urls.py "router.register" lines...

```
router.register('license_check', views.AgentLicenseBooleanViewSet, basename='meaningless')
```

The router.register "entries" are later added to the urlpatterns (in the same file) with this statement:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', include(router.urls)),
```

Then I added the AgentLicenseBooleanViewSet to the views.py file.  Note that it inherits from GenericViewSet to avoid making a bunch of other endpoints.  There's a bunch of testing code in the endpoint method - so I could see what's going on - but I left it in - in case it's helpful to someone.

In my case, I wanted a "custom" SQL query that returned simply "true" or "false" to the endpoint depending on what was found, so I used the "EXISTS" keyword.  See comments for more info on how the code works.

```
class AgentLicenseBooleanViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
"""Agent license boolean REST view
"""
# lookup_field is all we need in this case (unlike the other viewset classes) as we're only building a
# custom endpoint with a custom query that goes outside the standard Django model/serializer/queryset patttern.
# This is how you get Django to stop using the "default" primary key for the model or a plain "id"
# This shows up on swagger in addition to the two parameters declared on the url_path line below
# This parameter will show up on EVERY swagger endpoint created using this class's methods (see agents/urls.py)
lookup_field = 'agent_id'


@action(methods=["GET"], detail=True,
        # causes the parameters listed to show up on swagger and be passed into the **kwargs
        # uses "named group syntax" from regex as well as a regex.
        # And no, I couldn't find any way to get Django to show the id fields as ints on Swagger without having to
        # import a whole new swagger-related library
        url_path=r'(?P<state_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<authority>[^/.]+)',
        url_name='doesnt_seem_to_matter_probably_used_behind_the_scenes')
def has_license_in_state2222(self, *_args, **kwargs ) -> Response:
    print(kwargs)
    agent_id = int(kwargs['agent_id'])
    state_id = int(kwargs['state_id'])
    authority = kwargs['authority']
    print(agent_id)
    print(state_id)
    print(authority)

    print(type(agent_id))
    print(type(state_id))
    print(type(authority))

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        query = """
        SELECT EXISTS (
        SELECT id FROM agent_license
        WHERE agent_id = %s
        AND state_id = %s
        AND line_of_authority_code = %s
        ) as result;
        """

        # According to https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/sql-injection-prevention-django/
        # This is how to prevent SQL Injection on a "raw" query into the database from external input.
        # Django "scrubs" the endpoint method parameters passed in the array on the 2nd parameter (array)
        # in the cursor.execute(string, array) statement -- in order, using the %s "entries" in the query string.
        # Obviously, order of operation matters here.
        cursor.execute(query, [agent_id, state_id, authority])
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        result = row[0]

    # row will contain a tuple of (1, ) for true or (0, ) for false
    # depending on if the query returned "true" or "false"
    # we can use row[0] as an index into the array [False, True] and it will always return the right thing.
    return Response(data=[False, True][result])
```

Important note:  the lookup_field in the class is important to get that field into your endpoint.  I suspect it will add that field to EVERY endpoint you create within this class.

Also, note that the url_path line creates the other two parameters on the endpoint.

Finally - I'm doing a "custom" query here - NOT using the Django Model/Serialization/ConfigurationFilter approach here because I WANT to break that pattern.  It's important to sanitize the inputs to avoid the possibility of sql injection from some bad actor hitting your endpoint.  The code below does that on this line.

```
cursor.execute(query, [agent_id, state_id, authority])
```

See comments for more.  The %s in the query string (see query string setup) is replaced with the input parameters.  Obviously - order of operation matters here.  Put the right parameter in the right order in the array or your query will not work as expected.